# Would the computers be able to communicate if all of them had same name hardcoded in their OS? Why not?

Tags: computer-networks

> The name of a computer should never be bound into an operating system at compile time. Explain why.

I don't see a reason why this should not be allowed?

Say we have couple of computers all with the name "desertfx" hardcoded in the operating system. What's the downside of this. Not small downside like "unable to change it". I mean bigger downsides with respect to DNS.

[image]

Comment: It depends on how those names will be used, doesn't it?

Comment: You looked at a different question. "Multiple computers should not have the same name. Why? " For your question: So if I have three computers named X, Y and Z and I want each with the name built into the operating system at compile time, how would you do that? Do you think that would be clever? Now if I wanted to make 100% sure that nobody runs a hacked operating system?

Comment: And if I buy one of about 100 million iPhones (which is a computer with an operating system) in a store, how would that work? My iPhone's name is "gnasher's iPhone" and obviously Apple couldn't know that before I buy it. And if I sell it to you and you call it "barnyard's iPhone", what happens then?